# How do I achieve this shading effect in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I've been seeing this shading technique a lot lately, this is possibly not the best example of it but it's the only one I can find at the moment. How do you achieve this sort of shading in Adobe Illustrator? It's hard to describe so I haven't been able to google it... thanks very much in advance :)

[image]

[Source](http://dribbble.com/shots/203963-Balancing?list=popular&offset=28)

Answer (score 6):

It's texture. Typically done by scanning in whatever appeals to you (paint splotches, paper, metal, etc.) and then converting to a mask layer to apply over your color. You can do it in AI, though many folks do it as a final step in PS instead.

Answer (score 2):

What DA01 said. Here's a [tutorial that gives a good step-by-step example](http://www.shutterstock.com/newsletter/100/Creating_Grunge_Effects_in_Illustrator-1.html).